# What Hardware/Software/Security Would I be looking for when trying to start a gaming cafe?

Tags: internet

I want to make a gaming cafe in my area due to the one that was near me closing down. I know I need to find the reasons of it closing down, but also I'm not really sure on the software I need inorder to manage the different computers.

Not only software, but I've been thinking about hardware, what gaming rigs are affordable and what rigs I can either mass produce, or mass buy that can run the games that the gamers in my area want to play.

In terms of security uses, I'm thinking about trying to create a very large table that covers the corners of the walls (where the outlets are). From there, I will use external outlets that plug into the wall.

But with that, I will have the actual computers in a locked cubby, like a drawer with holes in the back for different cords. (No external use allowed to prevent viruses.

Advice on the gaming cafe would be nice. I live in a small town next to a big city that also only has of one well known gaming cafe.

Comment: Talk to the owner of the closing cafe.  Perhaps you can buy his business outright or much of his equipment at a discount.

Comment: Unless you have some sort of niche market then there is no way a gaming cafe can be profitable.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

- Disk-based CCTV camera recording system to capture theft and vandalism.
- Good idea about the 'cubby' but still buy **MANY** 'Kensington' locks.
- Don't go silly with high-resolution displays, 1600x1200 is the highest you want to go to, driving higher resolutions at acceptable frame rates needs disproportionately more expensive GPUs.
- Make sure any PCs you buy can be locked and figure out a way of locking your keyboards and mice to the machines too.
- Get the **CHEAPEST** keyboards and mice you can.
- Ensure members have to give you the details of a debit or credit card to join.
- Prepare for poverty.

Comment: +1 on the prepare for poverty

Answer (score 0):

Probably not quite what you're asking for but from a security/configuration/ease point of view I'd have thought that consoles would probably be the best way to start.

Answer (score -1):

I would definitely build your own machines.  It can be done relatively inexpensively via websites like [newegg](http://www.newegg.com/) and will enable you to replace components, which is easier than sending a whole cpu back to the manufacturer.

As for infrastructure, invest in good quality networking hardware (cisco comes to mind).

As for managing the workstations.  How many are you talking about?  Will you have a domain?  A domain would probably be the easiest route (via [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory)) to go for adding new users, removing users who are no longer paying, and managing passwords.  You can also manage the workstations by using [GPOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy) to lock them down, enforce password policies, etc.

Comment: What else would you send back to the manufacturer?  One of the cores?

Comment: You've never heard a workstation called a cpu?  And so you negged me for it?

Comment: thank you, all ideas will be considered.
These Answers lead me to another question xD.